# Issue with Routes not routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to get a url of example.com/p/21 to route to example.com/welcome/index/21. I have this line in my routes file

```
$route['p/:num'] = "welcome/index/$1";
```

If I go to example.com/welcome/index/21, it works fine. If I go to example.com/p/21, I get nothing.

In one of the queries, i'm passing in the number that is in the url and I echoed `$this->db->last_query()'`, and my query is showing `$1`.

How can I make this seamingly simple route work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
$route['p/(:num)'] = "welcome/index/$1";
```

Hope it works.